# Use get in threading macro

Tags: hy

The following three examples fail with the following errors:

```
(setv dct {1 2 3 4})
(setv dcts "dct")

;; (print (get (. (globals) [dcts]) 1))
(print (-> (globals) (. [dcts]) (get 1)))

;; (print (get (get (globals) "dct") 1))
(print (-> (globals) (get "dct") (get 1)))

;; (print (get (get (globals) dcts) 1))
(print (-> (globals) (get dcts) (get 1)))
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/home/shadowrylander/test.hy", line 5
    (print (-> (globals) (. [dcts]) (get 1)))
                                         ^
hy.errors.HySyntaxError: parse error for pattern macro 'get': got unexpected end of file, expected: some(...)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/home/shadowrylander/test.hy", line 8
    (print (-> (globals) (get "dct") (get 1)))
                              ^
hy.errors.HySyntaxError: parse error for pattern macro 'get': got unexpected end of file, expected: some(...)
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "/home/shadowrylander/test.hy", line 11
    (print (-> (globals) (get dcts) (get 1)))
                              ^
hy.errors.HySyntaxError: parse error for pattern macro 'get': got unexpected end of file, expected: some(...)
```

Is it not possible to use `get`, or macros in general, with the threading macro (`->`)? I've rewritten the print statements multiple times to ensure consistent brackets, and they're all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=> (require hyrule [->])

(setv dct {1 2 3 4})
(setv dcts "dct")

;; (print (get (. (globals) [dcts]) 1))
(print (-> (globals) (. [dcts]) (get 1)))

;; (print (get (get (globals) "dct") 1))
(print (-> (globals) (get "dct") (get 1)))

;; (print (get (get (globals) dcts) 1))
(print (-> (globals) (get dcts) (get 1)))
```

Comment: Er, quick question: where did you install `hy` from? `PyPI`'s seems to be broken due to `funcparserlib`, and neither `master` nor `alpha` seem to have `hyrule` either.

Comment: @ShadowRylander To install the latest alpha of Hy, just use the command pip3 install --pre --user hy . Or simply sudo apt install hy

Comment: That solved it; thanks! I didn't actually have to require `hyrule`, though...

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me on Hy master. Did you forget the `require`?

```
=> (require hyrule [->])
=> (setv dct {1 2 3 4})
=> (setv dcts "dct")
=> (print (-> (globals) (get dcts) (get 1)))
2
```

Comment: Er, quick question: where did you install `hy` from? `PyPI`'s seems to be broken due to `funcparserlib`, and neither `master` nor `alpha` seem to have `hyrule` either.

Comment: @ShadowRylander I am using Hy master, but Hyrule is a separate repository. https://github.com/hylang/hyrule

Comment: Actually, installing `hy` using `--pre` solved it, but I still didn't have to require `hyrule`. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477354/use-get-in-threading-macro/70477560#comment124583657_70477560; do you mind me giving the answer credit to the other user, given their lower reputation? They had the same answer otherwise.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted! Thank you both for the help!

Comment: @ShadowRylander `pip install hy --pre` gets you the most recent alpha release, not master. Hyrule was introduced since the most recent alpha release.

Comment: So is the threading macro a part of `hyrule`, or the core? Because I'm able to access it using `--pre` without `hyrule`.

Comment: @ShadowRylander It was part of core as of 1.0a3, but has moved to Hyrule since then.

Comment: Ah; fair enough. I guess I'll start importing it from `hyrule` then. Thanks again!